# How to test this block of code with POSTMAN?

Tags: javascript, postman, backend

I am currently working on a delete function on the backend so that only authorized users can delete their reviews if they want to. I am currently trying to test it through POSTMAN but I am getting the error "Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters".

Currently, my POSTMAN is set up where the user is already logged in and I used their auth token and set it as the authorization header for the delete function

```js
router.delete("/delete/:reviewId", requireAuth, async (req, res, next) => {
  const { user } = req
  const { reviewId } = req.params
  const review = await Review.findById(reviewId)
  console.log(reviewId)
  console.log(review)
  if (!review) {
    return response.status(422).json({ error: "Cannot find review" })
  }
  console.log(review.author._id.toString(), typeof review.author._id.toString())
  console.log(user.id, typeof user.id)
  if (review.author._id.toString() === user.id) {
    console.log("if is working")
    try {
      const removedReview = await review.remove()
      console.log("deleted review")
      const userUpdate = await User.updateOne(
        { _id: user.id },
        { $pull: { reviews: reviewId } }
      )
      res.json(removedReview)
    } catch (err) {
      next(err)
    }
  }
})
```

[POSTMAN setup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZSCu.jpg)

I currently don't have enough rep to embed the image into the post.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is surely related with `_id` that is sent to the mongoDB. You should check the validity of all `_d`s you used in this code block. The `_d` must be type of `ObjectID` to be precise. You can use `typeof` operator to determine its type. If it is other than `ObjectID` simply convert it.

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID; 
Model.findById(new ObjectId(yourId))
```

Let me know if it helped:)

Comment: I set my postman to use "_id" instead of reviewId and used the same id as the as test post to delete but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Made the changes you suggested but now it is giving me "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id'). So I'm guessing that was the original issue to begin with